# NL Refuse Stamp meaning and effect? What I can do to remove it?

Tags: schengen, passport-stamps, denial-of-entry, colombian-citizens

I am a Colombian citizen without EU residence. My boyfriend is German citizen and we were travelling from Tanzania to Amsterdam. I had already 90 free to stay in the Schengen area without visa.

When we were arriving at the Schipol border ask us the officer if have a proof for our long term relationship more then 6 months. We just had more then 1000 pictures with dates but after 3h waiting he said it’s for him not enough as a proof. He means we need to show a offical bank account or a contract from our flat what we didn’t have. The gouverment changed the rules 5 days before our arrival that pictures are not a proof anymore. After 2h discussion he allowed us to stay a night in the airport transit zone and take a flight to Croatia at the next day.

When he gave me my passport back I saw in the plane that stamp? What does it means ? And what consequence I have to care? Can I enter in the Schengen aera?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with “I had already 90 free to stay in the Schengen area”? You had already stayed for 90 days shortly before trying to enter the Schengen area? And were you given any form with an explanation about the refusal?

Comment: Border guards are also supposed to write a letter corresponding to the reason for refusing entry but it's difficult to read that on your picture.

Comment: Usually, what you should get is a form where the guard checks one or more boxes for the reasons that apply. If you scan or copy the relevant sentence, we might be able to tell you a little more. For the stamp, I don't need a super-high resolution picture but a sharp one would be better. Alternatively, do you see a letter (like  'A' or 'F') written somewhere near the stamp?

Comment: @Miau543 It’s not clear from your question how many days you’ve spent in the Schengen zone, and when. Where are you both resident?  Adding that information might help clarify your situation regarding future entry

Comment: You're right that the length of stay shouldn't be the issue. It's not relevant for EU citizen family members anyway.

Comment: Where were you going after Amsterdam? Note that there are additional Covid-related restrictions on entry in the EU and the Netherlands. If you are not recognized as a family member, you might not have had a valid purpose for that. If you provide more details on the Dutch-language papers you got, we might be able to verify this.

Comment: I know you are but was it the original plan you gave when first stopped at Schiphol? You're not supposed to undergo a border check if you are transiting between two non-Schengen destinations.

Comment: When a question is answered, the Stack Exchange rules do not allow for it to be deleted. The rules also do not allow for it to be defaced, so a roll back to the last full version is the norm. See here for what you can do: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221

Comment: @Relaxed (s)he's not a family member. Boy/girlfriends don't qualify as such, only spouses and children do.

Comment: @Relaxed seems they were transiting between a non-Schengen departure (Tanzania) and a final destination in a Schengen country (Germany) in which case Amsterdam was first port of entry and therefore where the border checks were performed.

Comment: @jwenting No, they were going to Spain. Originally the OP suggested they were going to Croatia. We had a long discussion (now deleted) to figure this out. The rules around family members are more complicated than that and in fact it seems the border guard did spend some time collecting evidence before reaching a decision instead of summarily rejecting the OP's claim. I just pointed out that the time limit wouldn't apply to family member for completeness as the question didn't seem to make a clear distinction between the two situations.

Answer (score 21):

This is a refusal of entry stamp. Unless you have also been banned (which is unlikely unless deception was involved), a refusal doesn't prevent you from reentering the Schengen area and won't be recorded in the SIS. You might reasonably expect additional scrutiny next time you cross an EU or Schengen border (or even possibly other countries' borders) so bring documentation to support all your claims. The things the Dutch border guard mentioned (joint bank account, rental agreement) would certainly seem useful if you hope to be treated as a member of an EU citizen's family.

From our discussion, it appears that the reason to refuse entry was

> Wordt beschouwd als een gevaar voor de openbare orde en de binnenlandse veiligheid, de volksgezondheid of de internationale betrekkingen van een van de lidstaten van de Europese Unie.

It's one of the standard reasons to refuse entry in the Schengen area. Prior to the Covid-19 pandemic, it wasn't very common but it does mention public health (*volksgezondheid*). Since the border guard wasn't satisfied that your relationship with a German citizen was enough to consider you a member of the family of an EU citizen, they have to apply the regular rules. And it is currently forbidden to enter the Netherlands from outside the EEA [except for trips deemed essential by the government](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/exemptions-to-the-entry-ban). It also means that reentering shouldn't be a problem at all once those restrictions are lifted (and you can easily explain that if you are asked about it in the future).

In any case, there is no way and no need to remove the stamp as you are still legally free to enter the Schengen area and border guards will not automatically refuse entry. Instead, they are supposed to determine whether your situation changed and you now fulfill the conditions for entry. You do need to figure out a good plan to secure residence somewhere for the next 6 to 12 months as travel is very restricted at the moment (and for good reason).

Comment: Also, it's entirely possible that this border guard made a mistake or was needlessly petty but you should not assume everything will go smoothly going forward. It's not helpful to dismiss him as a bad person, you will face others.

Comment: Additional: you should NOT try to “remove the stamp”. Not only is this unnecessary (as it is not a ban); but the Dutch authorities certainly have your details recorded in their computer systems. If you attempt to conceal, or destroy this refusal stamp, it will be considered deception - which WILL lead to a ban!

Comment: @ChrisMelville I took that to mean "get it cancelled or officially removed from the record", you're obviously right that tampering with it yourself would be a very bad idea.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119579/discussion-on-answer-by-relaxed-nl-refuse-stamp-meaning-and-effect-what-i-can-d).